# Elbow method for determining number of clusters on Mahout

Tags: hadoop, cluster-analysis, mahout

I'm using Mahout for clustering and I have implemented elbow method for determining number of clusters, so that I wouldn't have to specify it.

I have tried this on one machine, but now I'm having doubts when it comes to cluster of computers.

I have planned to use Oozie to simulate looping (running clustering algorithm each time incrementing the number of clusters by one). I read that Oozie is used for DAGs, but I see no other way of doing this.

The question is, does this look like a sound approach? If not, any alternatives?

Comment: Consider using something else than Mahout. If you can afford to try the Elbow method, your data set is probably not on the exabyte scale... you will be surprised how much faster other tools are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tools such as?

Comment: Scipy, ELKI, R (if you stay away from R code, and use built-in C and fortran code) will beat Mahout often by a factor of 10. Or more. If the data fits into memory.